# cakephp3 select count(*) from other models

Tags: mysql, count, cakephp-3.0

I have 3 models `Employees` `Customers` and `Partners`

I want to display the count of all the tables `employees` `customers` and `partners` in `dashboard` view of `Employees` model.

`EmployeesController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

class EmployeesController extends AppController
{
    public function dashboard()
    {

    }

}
?>
```

I'm new to cakephp and I have no idea how to query other model tables at all.

Please point me to good tutorial or documentation for this. It will be helpful

Comment: This is actually a database related question rather than specifically cakephp. Which database are you using?

Comment: @Takarii mysql is the database

Comment: ok, firstly take a look at this page http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

It outlines the querybuilder used by cakephp (the idea being to make it easier to write your own)

Comment: if you want to create your own query, you can use the format `$this->query('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id=? OR somefield=?')`

Comment: @Takarii in the controller? it that is the case how do i get the value to the view?

Comment: you would need to echo it to the html stream after obtaining the details. You would need to edit the source file to include those values obtained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using the following codes.

```
// Controller
$this->loadModel("Customer");
$query = $this->Customers->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Customers.area_cd =' => $this->Auth->user('area_cd')]
]);
$entity_count[0] = $query->count();
$this->loadModel("Employee");
$query = $this->Employees->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Employees.area_cd =' => $this->Auth->user('area_cd')]
]);
$entity_count[1] = $query->count();
$this->loadModel("Partner");
$query = $this->Partners->find('all', [
    'conditions' => ['Partners.area_cd =' => $this->Auth->user('area_cd')]
]);
$entity_count[2] = $query->count();

$this->set(compact('entity_count'));

// View
<?= $entity_count[0] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The query to use would be a nested query, assigned to an array. Then you can access the values from there.

In particular, you would want to write something like:

```
$result = List();
$result->query('SELECT COUNT(SELECT * FROM usertable), COUNT(SELECT * FROM partnertable), COUNT(SELECT * FROM customertable)');
```

To then access the values, you would refere to `$result` based on the position in the array, ie. `$result[0]` would be the first value, `$result[1]` the second and so on.

If you need to specify the items for the counts (such as active users, active customers etc) add where clauses into the select statements within the count expression

Eg. `SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE active="yes"`

Once you have the data you need, you can then edit the source file where you require them to be displayed and decide where to place them using a php echo to the html stream

Comment: So this code would go in the `EmployeesController > dashboard()` method and in the view `dashboard.ctp` i can include `<?= $result[] ?>`? am I right?

Comment: That should be the case. You will need to modify the SQL to meet your own requirements, but afterwards this should work fine.